# Call a service from a launch.py file in ROS2

Tags: ros, python, roslaunch, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Question**
Is there any possibility to call a service from a launch.py file in ROS2?

**Details**
I have written a python node with a service which is launched by a launch.py file. Within the same launch file I would like to call the service of this node multiple times (with different argument values). Is there any possibility to realize this in ROS2?

**Reference**
[call-a-service-at-startup-with-a-launch-file](https://answers.ros.org/question/11271/call-a-service-at-startup-with-a-launch-file/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384586/call-a-service-from-a-launch.py-file-in-ros2/) by [ffent](https://answers.ros.org/users/75061/ffent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2021-08-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This one is pretty straight forward, but took me a non-trivial amount of searching to find for myself. I posted this answer somewhere else recently, but since this question is the top search result, I thought I'd copy it here as well.

```
from launch.substitutions import FindExecutable
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess

...

ld.add_action(
    ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=[[
            FindExecutable(name='ros2'),
            " service call ",
            "/namespace/service_to_call ",
            "example_msgs/srv/ExampleMsg ",
            '"{param_1: True, param_2: 0.0}"',
        ]],
        shell=True
    )
)
```

Note the following:

- `ld` here is a variable containing an instance of `LaunchDescription`
- `/namespace/service_to_call` is replaced with the service you're looking to call (don't forget any appropriate namespaces) and can be found with `ros2 service list`
- `example_msgs/srv/ExampleMsg` is the message type used by that service, which you can get with `ros2 service info /namespace/service_to_call`
- `"{param_1: True, param_2: 0.0}"` is the dictionary defining the message data. To find the parameters you need to set, you may need to consult the `.srv` file or documentation.

Don't forget to include the `shell=True` argument, as the command will fail with a confusing "File not found" error without it.

---

Originally posted by [luckierdodge](https://answers.ros.org/users/116480/luckierdodge/) with karma: 56 on 2022-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks @luckierdodge! Just add more methods. Both examples below start a sim window and add another `turtle2`.

**Method 1**

Based on @luckierdodge answer:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess
from launch.substitutions import FindExecutable
from launch_ros.actions import Node


def generate_launch_description():
    ld = LaunchDescription(
        [
            Node(
                package="turtlesim",
                executable="turtlesim_node",
                name="turtlesim",
            ),
        ]
    )
    ld.add_action(
        ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=[
                [
                    FindExecutable(name="ros2"),
                    " service call ",
                    "/spawn ",
                    "turtlesim/srv/Spawn ",
                    "\"{x: 2.0, y: 2.0, theta: 0.0, name: 'turtle2'}\"",
                ]
            ],
            shell=True,
        )
    )
    return ld
```

**Method 2**

Based on https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Using-Event-Handlers.html

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess, LogInfo, RegisterEventHandler
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessStart
from launch.substitutions import FindExecutable, LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node


def generate_launch_description():
    turtlesim_node = Node(
        package="turtlesim",
        executable="turtlesim_node",
        name="sim",
    )
    spawn_turtle = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=[
            [
                FindExecutable(name="ros2"),
                " service call ",
                "/spawn ",
                "turtlesim/srv/Spawn ",
                "\"{x: 2.0, y: 2.0, theta: 0.0, name: 'turtle2'}\"",
            ]
        ],
        shell=True,
    )
    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            turtlesim_node,
            RegisterEventHandler(
                OnProcessStart(
                    target_action=turtlesim_node,
                    on_start=[
                        LogInfo(msg="Turtlesim started, spawning turtle"),
                        spawn_turtle,
                    ],
                )
            ),
        ]
    )
```

---

Originally posted by [Hongbo Miao](https://answers.ros.org/users/4114/hongbo-miao/) with karma: 70 on 2023-01-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found works with Services that have ***multiple/multiline*** arguments:

**Humble, Ubuntu 22**

i.e., this is the command line:

```bash
ros2 service call /namespace/service_to_call example_msgs/srv/ExampleMsg "param_1: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}
param_2: {x: -500.0, y: 160.0, z: -10.0}  
param_3: 0.05 
param_4: 0.001"
```

To run this from a launch file, I had to resort to this:

```py
def generate_launch_description():

    # start  service
    # Define service name, message type, and service arguments (as strings)
    my_service_name = "/namespace/service_to_call"
    my_service_type = "example_msgs/srv/ExampleMsg"
    my_service_arguments = f"""
    param_1: {{x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}}
    param_2: {{x: -500.0, y: 160.0, z: -10.0}}  
    param_3: 0.05 
    param_4: 0.001 
    """

    # Construct the complete command string
    command = f"ros2 service call {my_service_name} {my_service_type} '{my_service_arguments}'"

    my_service_call = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=[command],
        shell=True,  # **Caution:** Using shell=True increases security risk
    )

    return LaunchDescription([my_service_call])
```

- *Notice the extra **{ }** in the python **f** string.*

Honestly, I am not sure what the point of `FindExecutable(name='ros2')` is if I am just running a shell command from the launch file.

It would be much nicer if I could pass the service parameters from a YAML file, but I could not find any example so far...